# "Those who buy a second unit?"

Tags: grammatical-number

I am not a native English speaker. Maybe the question is stupid...

Each consumer chooses one of the two options: (1) buying one unit; or (2) buying a second unit. When I want to say some consumers (plural) who choose the option (1) or option (2) will do something, is it correct to say: Those who buy one unit will blablabla..., and those who buy a second unit will blablabla...

It is indeed correct to say: someone who buys one unit will blabla..., and someone who buys a second unit will blablabla.... When aggregating multiple consumers, should the "unit" also be aggregated as plurals or not?

Thanks!

Comment: He who buys one unit .... Those who buy one unit.... Those who buy several units....He who buys a second unit....Those who buy a second unit.....Those who buy several units.    A second unit is always one unit.  Several units are... well several units, plural.

Comment: Your sentence is not grammatical.  If there are **two** options, and the first option is "buying 1 unit", then the second option is "buying **2 units**' NOT "buying a **second** unit" (because you cannot buy a *second* unit until you have already bought 1 unit).  What about "If you buy 1 unit, you will ..., but if you buy 2 or more units, you will ...".  Or the second part could be "... if you buy at least 2 units ...".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, I might call option 2 a package, or package deal, then you just have people who purchase a unit vs people who purchase a package.

Then you can: 
People who purchased a unit will...
People who purchased a package will...

Other option to to say "people who purchased multiple (or two) units".